# ContentDialog closing on click outside app

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a reason for which a `ContentDialog` closes automatically when clicking outside the app window? The dialog async returned value is `None`. Is there a way to keep the dialog open, no matter the focus?

Comment: Glad you found the answer yourself. You should post your answer as an  answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

Subscribe to:

```
Closing += TheDialog_Closing;
```

in the handler:

```
if (args.Result == ContentDialogResult.None)
                args.Cancel = true;
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete code. It will help us a lot.